# Stripe: Do I need to refund for uncaptured charges?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, strip, catalyst

So in our app, we do not charge immediately but simply create stripe `charge` with `capture` set to `false` so that customer is not charged instantly.

Question: Should we still issue a `Refund` for the customer (in case of app/db error) despite the fact that we created a charge in un-captured mode ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ideally, yes, you should. "Refunding" an uncaptured charge will cancel the authorization and release the funds on the customer's account.

If you don't refund the uncaptured charge, the authorization will automatically expire after 7 days, but that's not very customer friendly. You should always try to either capture or refund uncaptured charges as soon as possible.

Comment: I am using this code to do the refund on the uncaptured charge `stripe.refunds.create(

    {charge: chargeId})` 
   Do you know if I use this code, Stripe would charge their fee on the refund amount that was NOT captured?